# What are invalid table names in SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql

So, apparently you can't name a table `Trigger` in SQLServer. Someone in my office found out the hard way porting an application from MySQL, I'm suspicious of whether or not that's a valid table name in MySQL either.

Is there a list of invalid table (or object) names in SQLServer?  Is it just all the keywords?  I'd imagine `SELECT select FROM select.select` isn't valid.  Is there ever a case where merely adding an underscore to the end of a keyword would still produce an invalid table (or object) name in SQLServer?

<sub>Question is in reference to SQLServer 2000 and up, but mainly 2005 and 2008</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use SQL server reserved words as object names as long as you wrap them in square brackets:
    Select [select] from [select]

However, I would NOT recommend this, and stay away from naming any SQL server objects after reserved names (or words that might be reserved in the future).

There was a list of these words in the SQL server documentation, they are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, now I need to take a big long grep